# How to ZIP files in FTP Server Directory

Tags: c#, ftp, zip

In my Application I need to download some files from the FTP server..I coded to download one by one via for loop and it works fine.My Problem is it is very slow process coz for each file it will gives credential. So if I can zip those files in FTP server it can be Download quickly..If there is a way pls guide me..
here My Code:

> Blockquote

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] list = GetFileList();
        DownloadFile(list, "e:\\sample\\");
    }

    private String[] GetFileList()
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(_remoteHost));
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        string FileNames = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string[] Files = Regex.Split(FileNames, "\r\n");
        return Files;
    }


    private void DownloadFile(string[] fileList, string destination)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= fileList.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost + fileList[i]);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destination + fileList[i]);
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());

            writer.Close();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: anyway for what? Zip the files?

Comment: If you want to zip the files *before* you download them you'll have to write software for / install software on the server which contains the files. Is that a possible option for you?

Comment: Provided that you can gzip the files on the ftp server when/before uploading them, [this snippet](http://quantcorner.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/downloading-and-decompressing-on-the-fly-a-gzip-file-from-a-ftp-server-in-c/) could be useful.

Comment: Do you have control over the ftp-server? If so  and you need to keep an uncompressed version of the file as well, you could write a simple windows service, with a FileSystemWatcher, that creates a zipped copy of each uploaded file, each time that it's modified/uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you initiate your FtpWebRequest once with the Username and Password and then use it in a foreach Loop for all files instead of creating a new one each round?

Another way would be to use a 3rd party tool (like: http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/) which may be faster, but its something you will have to test, take a looka t this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2343689/395659

A 3rd way could be to let a job running on the server which creates the ZIP file once in a period and you download it as a Zip file as mentioned in your Question.

Comment: Thanks @MeNoMore :D,
I think I have to create web request for the each file to be downloaded.So I have to create web request for the each file..
In third way cannot implement for me..it will restricte by the owener..
only way that I can see Using a third party tool...
Thanks Buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use the credentials, which might speed you up...

```
private void DownloadFile(string[] fileList, string destination)
{

    var myCred = new NetworkCredential(_remoteUser, _remotePass);

    for (int i = 2; i <= fileList.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_remoteHost + fileList[i]);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        request.Credentials = myCred;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(destination + fileList[i]);
        writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());

        writer.Close();
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the quick Reply buddy,
It doesn't speed up downloads..it will take 1.30 min to download 50 files(each 1.83kb). I got nearly **500 files**..:(

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET 3.0 or above you can make use of [ZipPackage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) present in the System.IO.Packaging name space. I haven't yet tried to zip files present on remote machines but you can give it a try else you may have to write a small job to zip the files and deploy it on your remote(ftp) server.

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh,
I have tried Zip Packeges with remote machines, I think it couldn't do with ftp protocols..

Comment: Then as I said you would need to write a small job and deploy it on the machine where the files are present. This job would zip the files which you can later download by FTP. You can schedule the job to run each time before you start downloading the zip file or you any other way which you prefer is good.